# C# Filter search Datatable with multiple rows using one textbox

Tags: c#, select, search, datagridview, datatable

I have created a filter search for my attendance monitoring system , it searches by the employee name but not with other fields, I think I'm gonna use the `LIKE` keyword but I don't know how to do it. Here's my code

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE [Firstname] like @1";
    command.parameters.AddWithValue("@1",textBox1.Text);
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.Update();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    connection.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code? do you have any errors?

Comment: Do you want to filter the DataTable or the database?

Comment: command.parameters.AddWithValue("@1",string.Format("{0}%", textBox1.Text)); Is that what you want?

Comment: In case your application gets more complex, I would advice using more descriptive names in the controls, events and parameters of the query. It will be a lot easier to mantain.

Comment: Try to build/concatenate your query with if else according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour matches exactly with the query you wrote, you should rewrite the query to match your requirements:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE [Firstname] like '%' + @1 + '%' OR [OtherColumn] LIKE '%' + @1 + '%'";
```

BTW, I have changed slightly your `LIKE` to make it behave like a 'it does contain XXX'.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I just passed my defense yester day :)